# Slack icon missing from top right corner in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, icons, slack

[image]

Slack icon is missing and shows this icon in its place.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the resolve myself. Uninstall slack, and reinstall again by downloading the .deb package. Don't install from the ubuntu software center.

Comment: Can confirm this worked for me also:  Slack Version 3.2.0-beta.2, Ubuntu 17.10 (using Wayland)

Answer (score 1):

Try editing `/usr/share/applications/slack.desktop` and change:

```
Exec=/usr/binslack --disable-gpu %U
```

To:

```
Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity /usr/bin/slack --disable-gpu %U
```

And then restart Slack.

[Source](http://www.dangtrinh.com/2017/04/fix-slacks-icon-tray-missing-in-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kevin. But, my /usr/share/applications directory doesn't have a slck.desktop file. So, I am not able to edit it. What can be done about it ?

Comment: If you were to create the file and add that second line, does it make any difference?

Comment: I also found this [relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9046) and [this upvoted fix](http://www.webupd8.org/2017/04/fix-appindicator-not-working-for.html), which is somewhat similar to what I posted except they tell you to have that file in `~/.local/share/applications`. Let me know what you try and how it goes.

Comment: I am not able to create the slack.desktop file at that location. It doesn't permit creating it. And I've been through the links that you sent me but none of them seem to work out. Is there anything else that can be done? 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you prefix creating the file with `sudo` or [have root access](https://www.wikihow.com/Become-Root-in-Ubuntu)?

Comment: I have created the file using sudo and edited it. I also restarted slack and my system but it doesn't seem to affect it.

Comment: There's `kill indicator-application-service` from [this thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-application/+bug/1728449). Also, if you launch Slack using `env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity slack`, there's still no indicator?

Comment: I realized a lot of these are `17.xx` fixes, so they may not actually apply to your case... I don't know - I'm kinda at a loss at this point. You could also try asking your question again at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) and reference the things you tried here.

Comment: On that note, I found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/871037/794515) over at AskUbuntu, and they tried `sudo apt-get install libappindicator1`, `sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386`, restarting and that fixed it for them.

Comment: okay Kevin. Thanks for your response. I will post the issue in AskUbuntu.

Comment: Try that last fix before you do so? That fix was from `16.10`.

Comment: I tried this last fix as well. It also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the icon path in Slack desktop.

1) Search for the actual desktop file:

```
$ grep "command=slack" -r ~/.local/share/applications/
/home/user/.local/share/applications/com.slack.Slack.desktop
```

2) Edit the file, and change icon path from `Icon=com.slack.Slack`, to an existing  image path.

For example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Slack
Comment=Slack Desktop
GenericName=Slack Client for Linux
Exec=/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=slack --file-forwarding com.slack.Slack @@u %U @@
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/slack.png
...
```